# cannot import to google cloud sql

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to import my database to google cloud. I followed the instruction given at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export#import-database

```
1. Go to the Google Developers Console and select a project by clicking on the project name.
2. In the sidebar on the left, click Storage > Cloud SQL to show a list of Cloud SQL instances for the project.
3. Select the instance into which to import data.
4. Click Import.
5, In the Import Data dialog box, set Format to SQL and specify the following:
A Google Cloud Storage path to a bucket that contains the MySQL dump file.
Optionally, the name of a database in the instance into which to import. 
You can leave this value empty if the input file specifies a database. 
If a database is specified, USE DATABASE is run before the import.
```

I was able to do all the step up to step 5, where I set the format to SQL but the path to the Google Cloud Storage path was grey and not editable, so I could not enter the path to the bucket where I import my data.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing.  The Cloud Storage path was initially gray.  Then I clicked my mouse on the path text, and I was able to enter text.  Does anything happen when you click the gray path text?

Comment: nothing. I tried it already but I can not type anything in the field

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this problem?